# Writing up findings from path analysis

Tags: reporting, path-model

I have obtained my results from a path analysis (using MPlus) and I´m not sure how go about writing a results section in APA style. The model is showing a nice fit to the data, my hypotheses are supported, and I have a clear idea of what my result mean, but I just don´t know WHAT statistics are conventionally reported in this kind of analyses and HOW to present them.
I have found a book, Kline (2010), and a couple of papers, McDonald & Ho (2002), and Boomsma (2000), but again, I feel unsure as to whether these may be good (or practical) references to do what I need. I feel a written example of a results section presenting a path analysis may help me, but I haven´t found any so far.
(This work is for my MSc dissertation, so space constrains for writing the results should not be a problem, although I do plan writing a manuscript version to potentially publish it. If you need additional information that may help with your answer please let me know). 
Could anyone please point me out in the right direction?
Thanks!

Comment: Nice question. One approach to this I might also make, is to do a literature search in journals in your discipline for "path analysis" (and perhaps "MPlus" also)... see how others have presented their results.